# Issue with Project Euler Number 2: Even Fibonacci numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int f=1;//first number
    int s=2;//second number
    int fin=0;//final answer
    int x;
    System.out.println("1\n2");
    for (x=3; x<4000000; x=f+s){
        System.out.println(x);
        f=s;
        s=x;
        if (x%2==0){
            fin+=x;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum of all even number: "+fin+2);
}
```

For some reason, I am getting `46137302` as my final answer when the actual answer is `4613732`. I am not sure why my answer is ten times the actual answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hav stumbled upon the nice String concatenation of java. The following works:

```
System.out.println("Sum of all even number: " + (fin+2));
```

You have to sum the numbers explicitly. Otherwise Java goes ahead and sums the values from left to right: Your String + the actual number, giving something like `"Sum of all even number: 4613730"`. And then it appends the `2` giving `"Sum of all even number: 46137302"`. But you want to sum the numbers first: you need to wrap them in `()`.

Answer (score 2):

That's how string concatenation works. you have to use `()`

take this example :

```
int x = 15, y = 25;

System.out.println("The answer is :"+ x + y); // The answer is :1525
System.out.println("The answer is :"+ (x + y)); // The answer is :40
```